# How to write a program to detect infinite loop in another program

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

During writing program I often come across infinite loop.

How can I write a program which takes another program as input and determine whether there is any infinite loop or not?

Comment: Are you asking if there's an out of the box library that solves the halting problem?

Comment: What you want to create is called a *static analyzer* and there are already many out there (both free and paid). But first of all you should [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Then you can combine debugging and static analysis to help find and solve problems in your code. Oh and don't forget to enable verbose compiler warnings, chances are that the compiler will be able to find a few issues itself.

Comment: Lastly, while some infinite loops might be a halting problem and therefore impossible to find, not all infinite loops are like that. Some infinite loops can be quite easy to find using analysis or even plain code review.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, I am asking if there's an out of the box library that solves the halting problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. And by that, I don't mean "it's really hard". I mean "this is a well-known problem in computer science that people have been trying to solve since the inception of the field, and if you could solve it you would immediately be world-famous."

Alan Turing proved that it cannot be solved, and no one has been able to disprove it, which is why I say "if you could solve this problem, you would be world famous."

See [The Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: You mean that the problem is hard but it can be solved. Can we have a proof that the problem has no solution and can't be solved in near future?

Comment: @Subhadip No. I mean the opposite. Alan Turing proved that it is impossible to solve in a general form that applies to every program.

Comment: @Subhadip If you read the link, you will see that is says that "Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for *all* possible program-input pairs **cannot exist**" [extra emphasis mine].

Comment: I'm tired of the halting problem being constantly mentioned in this context.  Alan proved it on a theoretical device with an infinite tape. Like most things in mathematics, when you shoe-horn infinity into the picture, it makes a problem undecideable.  Real computers don't have infinite tapes, and therefore the halting problem does not apply.  If a program can see the entire memory space of another program it can detect whether it is stuck in a loop simply by running it and finding a matching memory state; else the program finishes.  There is a realistic and programmatic answer yet to be given